# How to resize an image to be exact pixels (without having to manually drag it or crop) 2024 edition

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, resize, adobe-photoshop-elements

[image]

Hello everyone! Would love some input on how to resize an image without cropping. Usually I do the command T function and then manually drag and resize (since i want it to be the exact same size as my other screenshot) but after cups of coffee my hands get shakey and I am always a pixel off.

Comment: With the scale tool selected, in tool options along the top, you can type the size in the width or height box in pixels. Just make sure you type "px" as the unit directly after the size.